# How to not show the whole object of an API?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm not really sure how to name this question or what exact tags to use (will happily edit if needed).

In class we have to build a self contained system of a person (developer for example) with the following attributes: id, name, salary, contact information and skills. In Spring we create the HTML version that will be shown in the web browser, data bank and so on. 
We must save a log of all changes to the data bank but when calling "http://localhost:8080/person/api/events/" from the web browser - we must "filter" the salary out, so you wont be able to see it (so no one outside the system would be able to see it).

This is the person class (lohn = salary):

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "person_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_gen", sequenceName = "person_gen_my_sql", allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private long lohn;
    private String kontaktdaten;
    private String skills;
    private Long[] projekte;
}
```

The PersonController class has the following method included:

```
....
private void savePersonEvent(String type, Person person){
    PersonEvent event = new PersonEvent();
    event.setEvent(type);
    event.setObjekt(person);
    event.setObjektId(person.getId());
    personEventRepository.save(event);
}
```

The PersonEvent class is:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class PersonEvent {
    public PersonEvent() {}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "person_event_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_event_gen", sequenceName = "person_event_gen_my_sql", allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="personId")
    private Long objektId;
    private String event;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Person objekt;

}
```

And finally an EvenController class:

```
@RestController
public class EventController {
    @Autowired
    EventProducer eventstream;

    @RequestMapping("/person/api/events")
public PersonEvents feed(@RequestParam(value="last", required = false) Integer last) {
    if(last == null) last = 0;
    return eventstream.from(last);
    }
}
```

[One Person is in the DB looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRujj.png)

[When looking in the events "log"- "lohn: 50000" shouldn't be visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw8Ky.png)
(sorry, I'm no allowed to emmbed images yet)

I don't really understand how to **not** include the salary. And just setting it to 0 is not really what is asked from us. 
I could just introduce a new dummyPerson class that doesn't include salary but I am sure that there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could convert the `Entity` to a dto object containing only the properties you want to expose. Or you could annotate the field you want to omit from the JSON representation with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: In the EvenController class?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but you can use  [@JsonView](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) for exactly that

Comment: Thanks a bunch @The Head Rush that did that trick :)

Comment: @Cashbee I'll definitely read into it. Didn't know it existed. Thanks